# ampUrls batchGet JSON format

Tags: json, api, get, amp-html

I do not understand the documentation for the JSON package defining the URLs. I am using curl. I am able to pass my key to the API. I am having trouble with the url data. Below is what I have tried without success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
enter code here

 --data '{
  "lookupStrategy": "FETCH_LIVE_DOC",
  "urls": [
    "originalURL":"https://www.myurl.com/index.html", \    
    "ampURL":"https://www.myurl.com/index.html", \
    "cdnAmpUrl":"https://www-myurl-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/index.html"
  ]
}'
```

Comment: Have you tried to just pass an array of string urls without the added attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should be:

```
{
  "lookupStrategy": "FETCH_LIVE_DOC",
  "urls": [
    "https://www.myurl.com/index.html",
    "https://www.myurl.com/index.html",
    "https://www-myurl-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/index.html"
  ]
}
```

Looks like you are using the return data schema.

Comment: "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "www-myURL-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.myURL.com/c/s/index.html"
    },

Comment: {
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "www-myURL-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.myURL.com/c/s/index.html"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://www.myURLcom/c/s/index.html"
    },
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://www-myURL-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.myURL.com/c/s/index.html"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: These errors are expected. For example, "www-myURL-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.myURL.com/c/s/index.html" is not a valid AMP URL. What is your objective in using this API?

Comment: I have an AMP-only website. To make pages discover-able I used the canonical link to point to the respective AMP page.  The site as been uploaded to cdn.ampproject using the update-cache command. The command works, as pages can be accessed by typing the full www-myURL-com .... URL into a browser. However, the web pages do not appear to be discovered. That is, pages continue to be delivered from my web host versus the cdn.ampproject. My hope was that using this API would accomplish this.

Comment: Note, it is also possible that the cdn.ampproject is performing as intended. When I run Lighthouse on pages delivered from my webhost versus cdn.ampproject, pages delivered by my webhost have significantly better speed performance. In other words, it may be possible that cdn.ampproject recognizes this performance difference and defaults to delivery by the quickest method.

Comment: Discoverable relates only to search engines. Currently, search results will use the cache URL only on mobile platforms and only on valid AMP pages.

AMP cache is an explicit cache, and you need to use the 'cache URL' to get the cached results, it will not automatically redirect you to the cached AMP page from your web host. Check your search console, and if the pages you are concerned about are valid AMP pages, then you are OK.